# Execute Fortran compiled program with "exec()" command in PHP

Tags: php, exec, execution

I'm trying to execute a *.exe file (previously compiled with Fortran) inside a PHP script using the "exec()" command. I have succeded to do it for other *.exe files without inputs/outputs.

In this case, the program is required to read a text file that is located in the same folder than it. I would like to know how I should proceed for the execution of this program and how to deal with the fact of having this input text file for my program.

Comment: Have you actually executed it? It should be the same as a terminal/cmd call.

Comment: maybe your exec command should also contain a `cd` command so that your exe can locate the file. Something like: `exec('cd /path/to/exe/folder && file.exe')`